# Text rendering as Graphics slows down the performance in WPF C# .net 6.0. how to fix it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, rendering

backbuffer (WritableBitmap) contain all the data written after reading opentk lines.
opentk line rendering to imagesource is smooth if following text graphics are not rendered.
following codes are working but not smooth as before(without text).

```
var bm2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)backbuffer.Width, (int)backbuffer.Height, backbuffer.BackBufferStride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, backbuffer.BackBuffer);

backbuffer.Lock();
using (graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bm2))
{
 graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
 graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
 graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

//calling thousands of drawstring code inside method. For simplification, only below code is added as sample.method here

graphics.DrawString("MyText test only up5", new Font("Tahoma", 14), System.Drawing.Brushes.White, 10, (float)(OtkCanvas.otkHeight - 60));

}

backbuffer.Unlock();

OtkCanvas.imageSource = backbuffer;
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Graphics` is not WPF. Your problem has nothing to do with WritableBitmap. You may want to take a look at WPF's DrawingVisual and RenderTargetBitmap.

Comment: Why are you writing the text on the bitmap instead of adding it to a wpf canvas on top of the image? And your example is terribly confusing since the data in the bitmap is never copied to the writeable bitmap. If it works I assume it is copied, but it is not shown.

Comment: I would consider multiple layers as Jonas suggests. Put a textblock or multiple textblock even in a layer on top of the picture.